# Design a routing system

Tags: spatial-database, routing, point-of-interest

I am trying to develop an application, firstly web, later mobile, that builds a route based on points of interest, basically it should show the route and the points of interest and when the user clicks it will display some kind of information but I'm really struggling starting to create this...I already have my POI spatial database and I haven't really tried anything, because I don't know where to start. Is there any example you can give me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to gis.SE. Your question doesn't really say what environment you need to use (mobile, web, thick client - technology choices and tools would help). It doesn't tell us what you've already tried. It doesn't tell us what worked and what didn't work. It doesn't show us any of your sample data. It doesn't tell us about licensing restrictions. Can you edit your question (just click edit above) to include some more details so we may be able to provide a meaningful answer?

Comment: Postgis , pgrouting, osm2po and read little about graph theory and dijkstra and you know basics

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [OSRM API](https://github.com/DennisOSRM/Project-OSRM/wiki/Server-api#requesting-routes).

Basic point to point queries between the coordinates (*lat1*,_lon1_) and (*lat2*,_lon2_) are requested like this:

```
http://server:5000/viaroute?loc=_lat1_,_lon1_&loc=_lat2_,_lon2_
```

You get as JSON string in return.

Also you can build your own [OSRM routing server](https://github.com/DennisOSRM/Project-OSRM/wiki/Running-OSRM).